# For what values of $z$ the sequence $\frac{2^nz^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^n}}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I rewrite the sequence $\frac{2^nz^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^n}}$ as $2^n\left(\frac{1}{1-z^{2^n}}-1\right)$. The terms inside the brackets should go to $0$. It is possible only when $|z|<1$. Can we conclude like that? Becuase $2^n \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$. Am I going in right way? Is there any easy way to do this problem?

Comment: $z$ is real or complex?

Comment: It didn't mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that for $|z|>1$

$$\frac{2^nz^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^n}}=2^n \cdot\frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^n}}\to -\infty$$

and for $|z|<1$ eventually $z^{2^n}\le \left(\frac 1 3\right)^n$ therefore eventually

$$\frac{2^nz^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^n}}\le\frac{\left(\frac 2 3\right)^n}{1-z^{2^n}}\to 0$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit about the second conclusion?

Comment: The denominator tends to 1 since $z^{2^n}$ and the numerator tends to zero.

Comment: No I asked about $z^{2^n}\leq (\frac{1}{3})^{n}$. Give me an intuition for that please.

Comment: It suffices to show that when $|z|<1$ then $3^nz^{2^n}\to 0$.

Comment: Yes I get that, my doubt is how to prove that .

Comment: Assume wlog z>0 and $a=1/z$ then $$3^nz^{2^n}=\frac{3^n}{a^{2n}}=e^{n\log 3-2^n\log a}$$ and $$n\log 3-2^n\log a\to -\infty$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128567/discussion-between-madhan-kumar-and-user).

Comment: In the last just factor out $2^n$ and you are done.